# Unwanted new permission automatically added to a Windows's Registry key

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-registry

I have a specific problem with my Huawei Matebook M5 and the audio software (Dolby Audio X2), essential to have a good audio on speakers. This problem is also specific to the Lenovo Y700 laptop.

This program uses specific audio presets (Movies, Music, Games, Voice, and a personalized one). But no matter what preset I choose, when I put my PC in sleep mode, it changes to the Voice preset by itself.

After some investigations (I used ProcessMonitor), I found what's the cause of this problem, and proud of myself, I post an answer on a forum: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Gaming-Laptops/Y700-Touch-15ISK-Dolby-Audio-keeps-switching-to-quot-Voice-quot/m-p/4373579/highlight/true#M25338

In fact, each audio profile matches to a data value (0 for Movies, 1 for Musics, etc.) for the data ActiveProfile located at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Dolby\DAX`

Every time i put my PC in sleep mode, the AUDIODG.EXE process changes this value to 3 (the Voice preset).

A simple solution was to modify Permissions, and to remove "Everybody" from the list. It works, but only for a couple of days or hours and the problem reappears like a recurrent nightmare. The "Everybody" permission came back.

What can I do to avoid this permission to be automatically granted?

Before sleep mode:

[image: Before sleep mode]

After sleep mode:

[image: After sleep mode]

Auto-granted permission:

[image: Auto-granted permission]